# How do I make a countdown from 10 for a Bukkit Plugin?

Tags: java, bukkit

I am trying to make a Championships kind of plugin where there is a `start-game` command that starts the game after counting down from 10. However, I cannot find a way to wait 1 second as an interval in the countdown. I have tried `Object.wait(long)` and `BukkitScheduler.setRepeatingDelayedTask()` but neither of them are working out for me (`object.wait()` returns `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner` and `BukkitScheduler.setRepeatingDelayedTask()` errors in my editor). Anyone know a workaround to this?

Answer (score 3):

```
// See how many seconds have been counted
private int count;
private BukkitTask task;

public void doStuff() {
    // Reset count
    count = 0;
    task = new BukkitRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // If count is less than or equal to ten, increment count, otherwise set count to -1.
            count = count <= 10 ? count + 1 : -1;
            if (count >= 10 || count == -1) {
                // Cancel task if count is over 10s
                task.cancel();
                return;
            }
            Bukkit.getLogger().log(Level.INFO, "Seconds passed: " + count + "!";
        }
    }.runTaskTimer(YourPlugin.getPlugin(), 0, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use BukkitScheduler is the solution. But, it count in tick where `20 ticks = 1 seconds`.

So, you have to do something like this:

```java
private BukkitTask task;
private int count;

public void startTimer() {
   count = 10; // restart count down at 10 seconds
   task = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(MyPlugin.getInstance(), ()-> {
      // here what you want
      if(count == 0)
         task.cancel(); // cancel the task if the counter is finished
      count--; // reduce the counter
   }, 20, 20);
}
```

The first "20" is the time before starting scheduler. The second is the time between each call (both in ticks).

Also, don't use `Thread.sleep()` or `Object.wait()` because they could freeze the full server, and maybe timed out everyone...

Comment: How would I count down and then cancel the timer?

Comment: You can cancel what is returned by runTaskTimer. I will edit my answer

Comment: So, does it answer to your question ?